# Script batch does not work in a .bat file, but works if written in a command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, regedit

my question is that i have to delete from system registry every key and subkey that contain a specific word (that can change, it itn's always the same word)

until now i have created a script in Batch that export in a .txt file every key and subkey that contain the word i'm searching for, with a vbs script i can modify the name of the key (because the REG QUERY export key like "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" and REG DELETE need only "HKLM", then with another script i need to search every key (or subkey) the QUERY export and delete them. the script is like

```
SET /P keyword="insert keyword to search: "
REG EXPORT HKCU HKCU.reg
REG QUERY HKCU /f %Chiavediricerca% /s >logHKCU.txt
cscript replace.vbs "logHKCU.txt" "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" "HKCU"
FOR /F "delims=;" %i in (logHKCU.txt) do REG DELETE "%i" /va /f
```

now my problem is that if i write every line in a command prompt, the script work greatly, but if i put this code in a .bat file, the script stop when at the FOR command, closing cmd without displaying any error...

any suggestion? 
sorry if my english is not perfect, and thank for every help you can give me!

Comment: This is an incredibly error prone batch file, isn't it?  I'm not referring to the code itself, but the aim of the task - so much could go wrong with it.

Comment: Yeah, but i had to use it for some really specific word, that was impossible to delete the wrong key (registry key created from an old setup that now gives trouble, otherwise i had to search 32bit hash code manually in the registry)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In batch scripts you should double the percent signs on variables for the FOR command. This is noted in the FOR command help (`for /?` at the command prompt):

> To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
>   of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different
>   from %I.

Comment: God, it worked perfectly! sorry but i'm new to batch scripting 
Really thanks man